# Problem with passing Authentication Token to Django Rest Framework View from Vue.js Frontend

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework

I'm currently building a web application using Django Rest Framework for the backend and Vue.js for the frontend. I have set up token-based authentication using DRF's TokenAuthentication, and now I'm facing an issue passing the authentication token from Vue.js to the DRF views that require a logged-in user.

Here is my django setup

```
class CreateUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """Create a new user in the system"""

    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class CreateTokenView(ObtainAuthToken):
    """Create a new auth token for user"""

    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES


class ManageUserView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """Manage the authenticated user"""

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )

    def get_object(self):
        """Retrieve and return authenticated user"""

        return self.request.user

# view for board
class CreateBoardView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    # Create Board
    queryset = Board.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BoardSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # create board
        board = serializer.save()

        # create BoardUser with owner set to True
        user = self.request.user
        board_user = BoardUser.objects.create(
            board=board,
            user=user,
            is_owner=True
        )

        data = {
            'board': BoardSerializer(board).data,
            'board_user': BoardUserSerializer(board_user).data
        }
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Vue.js setup

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Rejestracja</h2>
    <form @submit.prevent="register">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" v-model="registerForm.email" required>
      <label for="first_name">Imie:</label>
      <input type="text" id="first_name" v-model="registerForm.first_name" required>
      <label for="last_name">Nazwisko:</label>
      <input type="text" id="last_name" v-model="registerForm.last_name" required>
      <label for="password">Hasło:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" v-model="registerForm.password" required>
      <button type="submit">Zarejestruj</button>
    </form>
    <h2>Logowanie</h2>
    <form @submit.prevent="login">
      <label for="loginEmail">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="loginEmail" v-model="loginForm.email" required>
      <label for="loginPassword">Hasło:</label>
      <input type="password" id="loginPassword" v-model="loginForm.password" required>
      <button type="submit">Zaloguj</button>
    </form>
    <h2>Utwórz nową tablicę</h2>
    <form @submit.prevent="createBoard">
      <label for="boardName">Nazwa tablicy:</label>
      <input type="text" id="boardName" v-model="boardcreateForm.boardName" required>
      <label for="boardDescription">Opis:</label>
      <textarea id="boardDescription" v-model="boardcreateForm.description"></textarea>
      <label for="dueDate">Data końcowa:</label>
      <input type="date" id="dueDate" v-model="boardcreateForm.due_date" required>
      <button type="submit">Utwórz</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      registerForm: {
        email: '',
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        password: ''
      },
      loginForm: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      },
      boardcreateForm: {
        name: '',
        description: '',
        due_date: ''
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async register() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/create/', this.registerForm);
        console.log(response.data); // Optional: Handle successful registration response
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Registration error:', error.response.data);
      }
    },
    async login() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/token/', this.loginForm);
        //console.log(response.data); // Optional: Handle successful login response
        // Assuming you will handle authentication token and redirect user after successful login
        const token = response.data.token;
        localStorage.setItem('token', token); // Zapisz token w localStorage
        console.log('Login successful');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Login error:', error.response.data);
      }
    },
    async createBoard() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/board/create_board/', {
          name: this.boardcreateForm.boardName,
          description: this.boardcreateForm.description,
          due_date: this.boardcreateForm.due_date
        }, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Token: ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          }
        });
        console.log(response.data); // Optional: Handle successful board creation response
        // Redirect user or perform other actions after successful board creation
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Board creation error:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: you should add the token in the headers.

Comment: ```
headers: {
            Authorization: `Token: ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
```
im doing it in CreateBoard()

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It doesn't authenticate even if you send the token correctly in the headers? Could you show me an example of your request?

Comment: login request:
{"email":"test@gmail.com","password":"123"}
login response:
{"token":"a9a60ef4c2c8ef52675beee38330c21b8ab02ddd"}

boardcreate request:
{"name":"test vue","description":"desc","due_date":"2024-03-25"}
boardcreate response:
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}

header for boardcreate:

POST /board/create_board/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Authorization: Token: a9a60ef4c2c8ef52675beee38330c21b8ab02ddd
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Managed to fix it
-typo in Authorization:`Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
and missing statment is setting.py in DRF
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',  # Add this line
    ],
}